# Tikz: How to add coordinate to node anchor?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I've got a question regarding positioning. Assume we have two nodes (A) and (B). (A) is placed left of (B):

```
\node (A) {A};
\node [left of=A] (B) {B};
```

We can draw an arrow between (A) and (B) like that:

```
\draw[->] (A.east) -- (B.west);
```

But how can I draw another horizontal arrow slightly above this arrow, e.g. something like `(A.east)+(0,0.5cm)--(B.west)+(0,0.5cm)`? (This doesn't work; it's just for you to understand what I am asking for.)

Comment: Thank you guys! I like all of your solutions. Pretty hard to choose the one to accept.

Comment: What I find very interesting is that you found a solution by yourself that is absolutely suitable. You just have to use the `calc` library, which is very very useful. Glad that you had so many different answers.

Comment: Haha, you are right. I just didn't use `calc`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node [left of=A] (B) {B};
  \draw[->] (A.east) -- (B.west);
  \draw[->] ([yshift=(2.5)]A.east) -- ([yshift=(2.5)]B.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

While `yshift` is a perfect answer to your question, note that you can also use the `calc` library to achieve this exactly like you asked:

[image: use of calc library]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \node (A) {A};
        \node [left of=A] (B) {B};
        \draw[->] (A.east) -- (B.west);
        \draw[->] ($(A.east)+(0,0.5)$) -- ($(B.west)+(0,0.5)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

like this (two soluces)

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node [left of=A] (B) {B};
  \draw[->] (A.east) -- (B.west);
   \draw[->,blue] (A.20) coordinate(dd)-- (dd-|B.west);
   \draw[->,red] ($(A.east)!0.5!(A.north east)$) coordinate(dd) -- (dd-|B.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass {scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}  
    \tikzstyle{vertex} = [ color=black, text=black, fill=black!10]
    \tikzstyle{edge} = [thick]
    
  \node[draw, vertex] (A) {A};
  \node[draw, vertex, left=of A] (B) {B};
  \draw[->, red, thick] (A.west) -- (B.east);
  \draw[->, green, thick] (A.150) -- (B.30);
  \draw[->, blue, thick] (A.210) -- (B.-30);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```